# Searching in columns separatly (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-material, filtering, angular7, mat-table

I want to use a filter on each column of my table.
Currently I'm using a general filter but that isn't the right approach.

```
// Component
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private dataSource;
  requestData: ITest[];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRepos();
  }

  getRepos() {
    this.reportService.getAll()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.requestData = response['tables'][0]['data'];
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.requestData);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  tableFilter(eventValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = eventValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
...
}

//HTML:

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Filter" (keyup)="tableFilter($event.target.value)">
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z2">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      ID
      <!-- <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="ID" formControlName="id">
      </mat-form-field> -->
    </th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el">{{el.ID}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  ...
</table>
```

How can I use the `FormBuilder` and formControlName for Filtering each column separatly? I found an example with the Module `FormControl`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not suppoed to directly touch the datasource. Material provides a high level of abstraction so that you actually don't have do it yourself.

Next, you should use a form control to manage that.

```
filter = new FormControl('');

ngOnInit() {
  this.filter.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(
      this.requestData
        .filter(report => report.yourField.includes(value) 
          || report.yourSecondField.includes(value)
        )
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: but I have more than one column. I think I need for each column a filter input field?!

Comment: No, you can have a single one, you just have to change your condition. I edited my answer to highlight it.

Comment: Yeah I understand your approach. But if I would have the value "10" in 2 columns in 2 different rows the table would return these 2 rows instead of 1.

Comment: Well that's what you asked for, being able to search in several columns. Thats means you should get two results, not one.

Comment: I wrote "..Filtering for each column SEPARATLY". I thought it is clear enough.

Comment: @yuro indeed, my bad on this one ! Then yes, you will need several fields. You can also use syntax formatting (`col:id 10`), but that's advanced for a lambda user, so I would indeed would advise you to have several searching fields.

Comment: Yeah I know. I tried it also with `FormBuilder` but it doesn't work. That was the reason why I asked if anyone have an idea to do it with `FormBuilder`.